# Positioning failure after two consecutive animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, autolayout

I am creating a fairly simple animation of several buttons and images in my app. Basically it looks like a menu that unfolds.

I use auto-layout storyboard to manage the view and I have set proper constraints so it looks the same on every devices.

I have two buttons and two images over these buttons, when first show,
`NSLog(@"Button position is %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_toclass.frame));
NSLog(@"Image position is %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_revel2.frame));` I get the answer : Button position is {{0, 153}, {600, 133}} and Image position is {{254, 179}, {92, 60}}.

I set the following variables and perform the first animation :

```
Hprofile = 20;
Hclass = 153;
Htuto = 2 * Hclass;
Hicones = 26;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.2
                      delay:0
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptions) UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{

                     [_toclass setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -Htuto, self.view.bounds.size.width, _toclass.frame.size.height)];
                     [_revel2 setFrame:CGRectMake(_revel2.frame.origin.x, -Htuto+Hicones, 92, 60)];

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 }];
```

After this animation (that works fine) is done, there is another button that you can use to come back to the previous settings :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptions) UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{

                     [_toclass setFrame:CGRectMake(0, Hclass, self.view.bounds.size.width, 133)];
                     [_revel2 setFrame:CGRectMake(_revel2.frame.origin.x, Hclass+Hicones, 92, 60)];

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     NSLog(@"Button position is %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_toclass.frame));
                     NSLog(@"Image position is %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_revel2.frame));

                 }];
```

After this animation the buttons are in the correct place but the images are not.
I get the answer : Button position is {{0, 123}, {320, 102.5}} and Image position is {{114, 179}, {92, 60}}.

I imagine there is some conflict between the animation and the auto-layout constraints, but I can't figure it out.

Help !

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using auto layout you should not change frames anymore, you should work with constraints.

As far as I can understand from your code, you want to move your button and image up and down. The correct way would be to create an IBOutlet from the top offset constraints in the storyboard (for both the button and the image) and change the constant on them so that it fits your animation.

Something like this instead of the first frame modification.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.2
                      delay:0
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptions) UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
    [self.buttonTopOffsetConstraint setConstant:-Htuto];
    [self.imageTopOffsetConstraint setConstant:(-Htuto+Hicones)];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Let me know if you need more help or something is unclear. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I'm afraid I don't understand what an "IBOutlet from the top offset constraints is". Is it another object or a constraint that I can modify programmatically ?

How can I create one of those?

Comment: So I search for the solution you recommended and I eventually understood what you meant. Given the constraints of the view I already settled, I, indeed, only needed to change the constant of one button constraint. Thanks to you I think I understand auto layout a little better...and it's huge..ahha
Thank you